# Prove that the groups $D_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I'm stuck trying to prove that:

Prove that the groups $D_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are isomorphic.

My attempt:
Let $D_6=\{e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b\}$ where $a^3=b^2=e$ and $ba=a^2b$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]\}$

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow D_6$ such that

$[0] \rightarrow e$
$[1] \rightarrow a$
$[2] \rightarrow a^2$
$[3] \rightarrow b$
$[4] \rightarrow ab$
$[5] \rightarrow a^2b$

Constructed in this way it is clear that f is bijective.

I'm stuck trying to prove that $f(a\cdot b) = f(a)*f(b)$ where $(\cdot)$ is the modular sum in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $*$ is the product in the dihedral group can someone help me?

Comment: You are going to have a lot of problems proving they are isomorphic, seeing how they are **not** isomorphic. That is, the reason you can't prove it is because it isn't *true*.

Comment: Just as a general strategy: if you get stuck at proving that something is true, try to prove that it is false for some amount of time. Understanding where you get stuck in proving that something is false might help in the proof of why it is true and vice versa. By switching back and forth a few times in the end you will find a path that works.

Comment: $D_6$ has $12$ elements ???...

Comment: Note also that your $f$ certainly doesn't work:  $b=f(3) = f(2+1)\neq f(2)*f(1) = a^2*a = a^3=e$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: There are two standard nomenclatures for dihedral groups: the index can be the number of sides of the polygon whose rigid motions you are considering (the convention you seem to be using) so that $D_k$ has $2k$ elements; or the index may be the order of the dihedral group in question (so in particular the index is always even). So while $D_5$ is unambiguous because it would not be used in the latter convention, $D_6$ may mean the dihedral group of six elements, or the dihedral group of the regular hexagon ($12$ elements) depending on your convention.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ArturoMagidin

Comment: $\Bbb Z_6$ has one generator, while $D_6$ has two. And isomorphisms send distinct generators of one group to distinct generators of the other.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo: You would need to *prove* that $D_6$ cannot be generated by a single element to carry that argument through. After all, $\mathbb{Z}_6 = \langle [2],[3]\rangle$, so now $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is generated by an element of order $3$ and an element of order $2$, same as $D_6$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin : Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth noting that a group of order $2p$ for an odd prime $p$ is isomorphic to either $D_{2p}$ or $\Bbb Z_{2p}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no wonder you can't solve this problem, because your statement is wrong.

If $\Bbb Z_6$ and $D_6$ are isomorphic, then $D_6$ must be abelian. But $(ba)(ab)^{-1}=a^2b(ab)^{-1}=a$, so $ab\ne ba$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb Z_6$ we have the element $[1]$ which is of order 6. Yet the maximal order of an element in $D_6$ is 3: for example the order of $a$ the 60 degree rotation.

Since isomorphism preserves the order of elements (nice exercise) we can deduce that both groups aren't isomorphism to each other.

Fun fact: this is a special case of a $pq$ group.
For two primes $p<q$ such that $p\mid q-1$, there are **exactly 2** groups of order $p \cdot q$ (up to an isomorphism), one of which is Abelian while the other isn't.
This fact can be proved using the Sylow theorems.